# If $X$ is a compact metric space and $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous map , where $Y$ is another metric space , then is $f(X)$ a complete subset of $Y$ ?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

If $X$ is a compact metric space and $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous map , where $Y$ is another metric space , then is $f(X)$ a complete  subset of $Y$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is a compact. Moreover since $Y$ is a metric space, $f(X)\subset Y$ is also a metric space. Finally, you know that every metric space that are compact are complete, therefore $f(X)$ is complete.